# ObservableBoolean is not getting observed in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-context

here is my class, progress bar is not showing up while debugging its true and still not visible on view

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_abc,
        container,
        false
    )
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        InventoryLocationItemsViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity!!.application)
    ).get(InventoryLocationItemsViewModel::class.java)


    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    setupObservers()
    makeAPICall() 
}
private fun setupObservers() {
    viewModel.isProductExists.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        deleteInventoryProduct(it)
    })
```

viewmodel is

```
    class InventoryLocationItemsViewModel(
    val context: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(context) {
    val dataLoading = ObservableBoolean(false)
    fun makeAPICall() {
        dataLoading.set(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your setupObservers() function ?

Comment: why not use mutable live data ?

Comment: @Abdul added. but there is nothing to do with that

Comment: Can you post the snippet where ' viewModel.isProductExists' gets set?

Comment: its gets set in nonsuccess call in makeAPICall function

Comment: Is the dataLoading variable bound in the xml?